# Add a new layer below labels for deck.gl

Tags: deck.gl

It is probably very easy but I couldn't find how to add a new layer below the labels for [deck.gl](https://github.com/uber/deck.gl) which uses Mapbox GL JS under the hood. For mapbox gl it is explained [here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-layer-in-stack/).

I searched their docs also for z-index or picking the label layer from the vector tiles source but without success so far.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone stumble upon this question in 2022, you might want to have a look at the [Mapbox Deck.gl](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/mapbox/overview) submodule which will help you achieve this behaviour.

Here is the documentation: https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/mapbox/overview

Answer (score 0):

As of June 2018 [there is no simple solution](https://github.com/uber/deck.gl/issues/1980).